# CakePHP - How do I link these models together (that requires use of a relation table)?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, relation

I'm currently using CakePHP 2.0-RC1. Being pretty nifty and all, I've only come across one challenge that I can't wrap my mind around. I've read the documentation on linking models together (http://www.cakedocs.com/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), but how to I tell CakePHP to search trough a relation table and find the values I'm after? Let me explain.

I have a database structure similar to the following (it has been simplified for the question. PK = Primary Key. FK = Foreign Key )

**game**

```
 - INT(11) id (PK)
 - VARCHAR(100) name
 - VARCHAR(40) year
 - VARCHAR(10) age
```

**category**

```
 - INT(11) id (PK)
 - VARCHAR(50) name
```

**game_category**

```
 - INT(11) game_id (FK)
 - INT(11) category_id (FK)
```

**Explanation to the relationship between these:**

A game can have one or more category. This relation is defined in "game_category" table. I want CakePHP to not only find what category id a game has, I want the category name as well when I do $this->Game->find('first') for instance. I would guess CakePHP needs to be told to "continue through the game_category table and onto the category table" and find what the name of each category actually is.

I have these Models

**Game.php**

```
<?php
class Game extends AppModel {
    var $useTable = 'game';

    var $hasMany = array(
    'GameCategory' => array(
        'fields' => '*',
        'className' => 'GameCategory',
        )
    );

    var $hasOne = 'Review';  
}
?>
```

**GameCategory.php**

```
<?php
class GameCategory extends AppModel {
    var $useTable = 'game_category';

    var $belongsTo = 'category';

    var $hasMany = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'fields' => '*',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'className' => 'Category',
        'conditions' => array('GameCategory.game_id' => 'Game.id', 'GameCategory.category_id' => 'Category.id'),
    )
    );
}
?>
```

**Category.php**

```
<?php
class Category extends AppModel {
    var $useTable = 'category';   
    var $belongsTo = 'GameCategory';
}
?>
```

By the relations defined above, I get results like this:

```
Array
(
    [Game] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Colonization
            [year] => 1995
            [age] => 7
        )

    [GameCategory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [game_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 19
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [game_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 16
                )

        )
)
```

The only thing remaining is just getting the actual name of each category. I hope some of this made any sense.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your join table - game_category, has an 'id' primary key field as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see [hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) in book online and should change table name game_category to games_categories for correct conventions.

**Game.php**

```
<?php
class Game extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Game';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Category' =>
        array(
            'className'              => 'Category',
            'joinTable'              => 'game_category',
            'foreignKey'             => 'game_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'category_id',
        )
);
```

}
?>

Comment: the names should be in alphabetical order, so most properly, categories_games :)

Answer (score 0):

all table names must in plural ( games, categories ) 
wrong category association, must hasAndBelongsToMany 
use cake console ( ./cake bake ) to prevent future errors like this

```
<?php
class Category extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Category';
    var $displayField = 'name';
    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Game' => array(
            'className' => 'Game',
            'joinTable' => 'game_categories',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'game_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );

} 
<?php
class Game extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Game';
    var $displayField = 'name';
    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

    var $hasMany = array(
        'GameCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'GameCategory',
            'foreignKey' => 'game_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}

#games
$games = $this->Game->Category->find('all');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already invoked Cake's inflector so that I can use table "category" instead of "categories".

Comment: yes you can, but cakephp developers added these rules for more clarity. In model you can define property `$useTable`, but do it for tables without singular noun ( e.g. news ) or abbreviations.

Comment: Also, your example got it the wrong way around. The correct usage must be $this->Game->find('first') so that I can find one game, and it magically adds up the categories with IDs and names.